# How to have only one textediting controller for multiple textfields in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Writing multiple text editing controller for multiple texts makes the code so long . Does anyone know how to write only one text editing controller and provide multiple texts in flutter ??

Comment: Could show your code? I am not sure why multiple controllers should have a massive impact, it takes just one line to define them `final TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();` .

Answer (score 1):

Having multiple controllers won't slow down your code. And it's always better to avoid any misconfigurations for your text. So it's better to use different controllers for each text field as you could perform functions on specific text field data

Answer (score 0):

create one TextEditingController

create a map containing all your different text values

encode the map so that it can be passed to TextEditingController

pass the encoded map to the TextEditingController for it's text parameter

update the relevant key in the map as required when the state changes

Comment: It would be better if you had written a example.